# OpenSL audio controlled by global equalizer/effects

Tags: android, opensl

Is it possible for an OpenSL application to be registered in the global output mix so that apps such as the default "Audio Effects" app (the one that opens when you select the equalizer in Google Play Music, for example) or other global equalizer/effects apps can effect it? It seems many apps are not affected by these global equalizers, so is it not notice possible with OpenSL?

Comment: have you come to a conclusion?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, I found some discussion on it. You would have to use AudioTrack. Affecting the global mix is deprecated in general however.

Comment: that's a pity...

Comment: could you please direct me to that discussion? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ndk/128b3bakk9/opensl-audio-session-id-for-3rd-party-equalizer-apps for example